# Question about the standard approximation argument, approximate a functional whose variable is $\varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to ask a question about the standard approximation argument while reading something about stable solution of elliptic PDE [Remark 1.1.1](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=lP_LBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=stable%20outside%20a%20compact%20set&source=bl&ots=l6I2A2BHkr&sig=ACfU3U0LaVoD_Vea8jpe6Cyb3CKmBWDDxg&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=stable%20outside%20a%20compact%20set&f=false).

We set the following definition, we say $u$ is stable solution of $-\Delta u=f(u) \ \text { in } \Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ if it satisfies the following definition. Here $u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $f \in C^1(\Omega)$.
$$
Q_u(\varphi):=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \varphi|^2 d x-\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) \varphi^2 d x \geq 0, \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega),
$$
then **using a standard approximation argument, if $\Omega$ is bounded or merely if $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$ is bounded in $\Omega$, one can take $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ in the above definition.**

I want to ask

1.If $\Omega$ is bounded then function in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ can be approximated by a sequence of functions in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, besides, since $\Omega$ is bounded, so $f^{\prime}(u)$ is also bounded, then the approximation is simple.

2.If $\Omega$ is unbounded, then function in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ can also be approximated by a sequence of functions in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ ? I can't find appropriate reference, so I'm not sure if this is right.

Besides, for $\Omega$ unbounded, why we only want $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$ to be bounded?
$$
Q_u(\varphi):=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla \varphi|^2 d x-\int_{\Omega} (f^{\prime}(u)^+-f^{\prime}(u)^{-}) \varphi^2 d x \geq 0, \quad \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega),
$$
if we want the approximation, don't we need that $|f^{\prime}(u)|$ is bounded?

Comment: It depends on the definition of $H^1_0$ you are using. The (standard?) way would be to define $H^1_0$ as the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ under the $H^1$-norm. Then the answers to your questions are immediate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The remark said that the two definition is equal when $\Omega$ is bounded or $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$ is bounded. $Q_u(\varphi) \ge 0$, $\forall \varphi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ obviously implies $Q_u(\varphi) \ge 0$, $\forall \varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$.  The opposite direction should also be correct if we let $\left|f^{\prime}(u)\right|$ is bounded, but here they merely let  $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$to be bounded, I'm not sure about this step.

Comment: My guess is that to the term $f'(u)^+\varphi^2$ you can apply something like Fatou's lemma and, exploiting the convergence of the negative part and the gradient integral, combine them to obtain the nonnegativity of the whole expression in the limit.

Comment: Yes, for the approximation process, rewrite $\int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla \varphi_n\right|^2 d x-\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u) \varphi_n^2 d x \geq 0$ as $\int_{\Omega}\left|\nabla \varphi_n\right|^2 d x+\int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u)^{-} \varphi_n^2 d x \geq \int_{\Omega} f^{\prime}(u)^{+} \varphi_n^2 d x$, then use the fatou lemma on the RHS, so we only have to let $f^{\prime}(u)^{-}$to be bounded.